# Dfs algorithm that decides if a directed graph has a unique topological sort

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to struct an algorithm that uses DFS for the purpose of deciding whether a given directed graph has unique topological sort or not. 
My approach to the problem is that only a specific graph has a unique topological sort. And that graph is a chain like graph, in which all of the vertices are connected to each other in one line.
My dilemma is how to do an efficient  DFS algorithm, and what exactly should I check.

Comment: Other kinds of graphs have unique topological sorts, like a->b, b->c, a->c.  They would all become "chain graphs" if you did a transitive reduction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).  Do you need to use DFS for this?  It's not the easiest way

Comment: Yea that's the point. To use an efficient DFS algorithm to solve it

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/)

> a digraph has a unique topological ordering if and only if there is a directed edge between each pair of consecutive vertices in the topological order (i.e., the digraph has a Hamiltonian path).

So, you run DFS and you need to check that the longest path you went from start vertex has length |V|, then you have unique topological order. As MattTimmermans pointed out such graph can be reduced to a "chain graph".

Comment: Sorry i just didn't understand what do you mean by leg. Do i need to check if there is a path between all consecutive vertices? If it's the length of V then its a unique topological sort?

Comment: @elads11 yes, but if you don't know from which vertex to start, then worst case complexity will be `O(N!)`. You can read more [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/hamiltonian-path/tutorial/)

Comment: @elads, if you have a vertex with no incoming edges, you certainly know from where to start.