# checking if a directed graph has only single one topological sort

Tags: directed-graph, topological-sort

I'm trying to write pseudo-code for an algorithm that suppose to check whether a directed graph has only single one topological ordering. I've already come up with the pseudo-code for a topological sort (using DFS), but it does not seem to help me much. I wonder if there is no sinks in that graph -then  there's not a single one topological ordering (might it help?).

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032061), as the best possible runtime is improved when it starts at a vertex with no outgoing edges.

If your directed graph has `N` vertices, and you have exactly one starting vertex with indegree 0,

- Do DFS (but only on the starting vertex) to get a topological sort `L`.
- If `L` doesn't have `N` vertices, either some vertices are unreachable (those are part of a cycle) or you need another starting vertex (so there are multiple toposorts).
- For `i` in `[0,N-2]`,

  - If there is no edge from `L[i]` to `L[i+1]`,

    - Return false.
- Return true.

---

Alternatively, modify Kahn’s algorithm: if more than one vertex is in the set (of vertices of indegree 0) while the algorithm is running, return false. Otherwise, return true.